# Rails asset compilation error

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, sass

По время компиляции CSS (rake assets:precompile) получаю ошибку:

```
sergey@Iron-book ~/repos/git/fws $ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$grid-float-breakpoint".
/home/sergey/repos/git/fws/app/assets/stylesheets/landing/_navbar.scss:98
```

Далее привожу последовательность подключения таблиц стилей и фрагменты конфигурационных файлов.

```
├── images
├── javascripts
│   ├── active_admin.js.coffee
│   ├── application.js
│   ├── feedback.coffee
│   └── landing.coffee
└── stylesheets
    ├── active_admin.css.scss
    ├── application.css.scss
    ├── feedback.scss
    ├── landing
    │   ├── _features.scss
    │   ├── _feedback.scss
    │   ├── _navbar.scss
    │   └── _registration.scss
    └── landing.scss
```

---

```
# Gemfile

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

---

```
# assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.gif *.png *.ico )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.sass *.sass )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.scss *.scss )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.css.erb )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.js.coffee *.js.coffee.erb )
```

---

```
# development.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }    

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.    

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false    

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false    

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false    

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false    

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log    

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load    

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true    

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true    

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true    

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

---

```
# application.css.scss

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "landing";
```

---

```
# landing.scss

@import "landing/navbar";
@import "landing/registration";
@import "landing/features";
@import "landing/feedback";
```

---

```
#_navbar.scss

...
@media (max-width: $grid-float-breakpoint) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    > li > a {
      color: $colDefault;
      &:hover, &:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
      }
    }
    > .active {
      > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
        color: $colHighlight;
        background-color: $bgMenuHighlight;
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

На мой взгляд стили подключены верно.
Коллеги, помогите найти ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, у вас не определена переменная [$grid-float-breakpoint](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L335)

Comment: Переменная $grid-float-breakpoint определена именно там где вы указали, в [_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L335),
 который включается в [_bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss#L8)

Comment: @SergeyLarin сообщение об ошибке говорит, что нет. В других окружениях (без прекомпиляции) нормально работает, не сыплет ошибками?

Comment: @SergeyLarin RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace покажет то же самое? config/development.rb покажите ещё

Comment: @SergeyLarin то есть то же самое (-: а config/development.rb добавите?

Comment: @Vetal4eg, да. Абсолютно тот же трейс.
Пардон. Так и не добился нормально форматирования трассировки в комментарии. Пришлось удалить.

Comment: @Vetal4eg, добавил development.rb к описанию проблемы.
Но я не помню что бы менял его.

Comment: @SergeyLarin в комментах нет форматирования кода, это да.

Comment: @SergeyLarin проверки ради, в assets.rb замените всё на эту строчку: Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( * )

Comment: @SergeyLarin для таких штук я использовал бовер - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#bower-with-rails

Comment: @Vetal4eg, по поводу
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( * )   

Тот же трейс.  
Я так понимаю потому что, больше не меньше.  

За Bower спасибо. Сейчас посмотрю что за зверь.

Answer (score 0):

@Vetal4eg, строго говоря вы были правы когда сказали очевидный факт.
Переменная не определена.

```
# assets.rb

...
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.sass *.sass )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.scss *.scss )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.css.erb )
...
```

Ошибка крылась в этих стоках.
Дело в том что при разборе таблиц стилей в компилятор sass вычитывает все файлы чьи расширения подходят по шаблон указанный выше.
Довольно очевидный факт.

Но ошибка заключалась в том, что в случае когда разбор начинался не с application.css.scss а непосредственно с _alerts.scss, _alerts.scss сам по себе не включает определение некоторых переменных.

Например $grid-float-breakpoint определена в _vareables.scss который включён в bootstrap.scss.

Проблему решило не сложное регулярное выражение, запрещающее начинать разбор таблиц стилей с парциалов начинающихся с '_'.

```
# assets.rb

...
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/^[^_]\w+\.(css|css.erb|css.sass|sass|css.scss|scss)$/]
...
```

Так же вы должны включить определения переменных bootstrap непосредственно в парциал в котором вы собираетесь их использовать, или в родительскую таблицу:

```
# landing.scss или _navbar.scss в моём случае

// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
...
```